# Find the position vector of the point of intersection

Tags: vectors

The line l has equation $\vec r = i + 2j - k + \lambda(3i - 2j + 2k)$ and the plane $p$ has equation $2x + 3y - 5z = 18$.

$i)$ Find the position vector of the point of intersection of $l$ and $p$.

How can I tackle this type of question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: write your straight line in the form
$$x=2+3\lambda$$
$$y=2-2\lambda$$
$$z=-1+2\lambda$$
plugging this in the equation of your plane
$$2(2+3\lambda)+3(2-2\lambda)-5(-1+2\lambda)=18$$
solve this for $$\lambda$$ and insert this value in the equation of your line and you will get the intersection Point
let $$\vec{n}=(2;3;5)$$ and $$\vec{a}=(3;-2;2)$$ then $$\cos(\phi)=\frac{|\vec{n}\cdot \vec{a}|}{|\vec{n}||\vec{a}|}$$

Comment: Thank you, how would I find the acute angle between $l$ and $p$?